# What is the most efficient and fastest way to migrate a set of MySQL databases?

Tags: mysql, import, export, database-migration

I have the following setup:

- MySQL instance having 200 databases identical in structure but containing different data
- I have to move the 200 databases from one hosting provider to another
- both hosting providers are beind VPN without possibility of connecting them directly

We have tried the following approach:
1. mysqldump for each database on the source db using

`mysqldump --single-transaction -u root -p --add-drop-database --databases dbX | pv | gzip -9 > dbX.gz`

2. import every database dump in the destination database using

`gunzip < dbX.gz | mysql -u root -p`

The dump of 200 databases (X = 1 to 200) took about 1.5h with the total size of the .gz files at about 2.5GB

The import of the 200 db's took 7.5 hours

The problem is that we have to perform the export/import within a minimum time window since we have to take our production environment offline.

Is there any method through which we can speed this process up?

Our target would be a max. of 4 hours.

Comment: I haven't tried it but MySQL started offering incremental backups - if it works you just do the migration at your leisure then to a final - and much faster since it will be much smaller - incremental. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the response, this could be one method, any other suggestions?